# Create new columns based on data based on factor values in another column in R

Tags: r, database, split

I have some data as follows

```
id <- c( 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)
field <- c("A", "A; B; D", "B", "B; C; E", "F; J", "G", "H; I", "B; F", "F;H;J", "D;F", "C;I")
d <- as.data.frame(cbind(id, field))
d
   id    field
1   1        A
2   2  A; B; D
3   3        B
4   4 B; C; E;
5   5     F; J
6   6        G
7   7     H; I
8   8     B; F
9   9    F;H;J
10 10      D;F
11 11      C;I
```

I do not know in advance how many possibile cases the variable `field` can take but I know they are separated by `;`.  In this example there are 10 possible values being any letter from `A` to `J`.

Given the above, I need to create `n` new columns, where `n` is the number of possible values in `field`. Then, in each new column, observations should take value `1` if the column name is included in `d$field`, `0` otherwise.  Taking only the first two rows in the above example, the new data will be as follows:

```
d_new
  id   field A B C D
1  1       A 1 0 0 0
2  2 A; B; D 1 1 0 1
```

How can I do this?

If that matters, I have a relatively big dataset with > 500.000 observations and potentially 30+ values in `field`.

I tried to make something out in the same spirit as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64242832/create-new-column-based-on-factor-and-numeric-data) combining it with `str_split(d$field, ";")`, but I can't find a way to get what I need.

Comment: `splitstackshape::cSplit_e(d, 'field', ';\\s*', fixed = FALSE, type = 'character', fill = 0)`

Comment: `library(dplyr); library(tibble); d %>% separate_rows(field) %>% table %>% as.data.frame.matrix %>% rownames_to_column(var = "id") %>%
mutate(id = as.numeric(id)) %>% arrange(id)`